# Sort Counter by frequency, then alphabetically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

I am trying to use counter to sort letters by occurrence, and put any that have the same frequency into alphabetical order, but I can't get access to the Value of the dictionary that it produces.

```
letter_count = collections.Counter("alphabet")
print(letter_count)
```

produces:

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'l': 1, 't': 1, 'p': 1, 'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'b': 1})
```

How can I get it ordered by frequency, then by alphabetical order, so everything that shows up only once is in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like your question is how to sort the entire list by frequency, then break ties alphabetically. You can sort the *entire list* like this:

```
>>> a = sorted(letter_count.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
>>> print(a)
# [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('e', 1), ('h', 1), ('l', 1), ('p', 1), ('t', 1)]
```

If you want the output to be a dict still, you can convert it into a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> collections.OrderedDict(a)
# OrderedDict([('a', 2),
#              ('b', 1),
#              ('e', 1),
#              ('h', 1),
#              ('l', 1),
#              ('p', 1),
#              ('t', 1)])
```

This preserves the ordering, as you can see. `'a'` is first because it's most frequent. Everything else is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: As I understand it, that was said because the entry that occurs twice had already been put at the front of the list; the OP wanted the ties between the hapaxes broken alphabetically.

Comment: That's right, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: `lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]` How does this exactly work?

Comment: @kirtipurohit, minus sign for using **reverse** sorting (par ```reverse``` was not used). For pair ```(item[1], item[0])``` sorting first sorts on ```item[1]``` and then, if items are equal on ```item[1]```, sorts on ```item[0]```. ```item[1]``` here is frequency, meanwhile ```item[0]``` is a char symbol

Answer (score 6):

You can sort the input before passing it to the counter.

```
>>> Counter(sorted("alphabet")).most_common()
[('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('e', 1), ('h', 1), ('l', 1), ('p', 1), ('t', 1)]
```

Comment: Note that this is only guaranteed to work in Python 3.7 (released June 2018) or higher, when dictionaries became sorted by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
letter_count = collections.Counter("alphabet")

the_letters = [a for a, b in letter_count.items() if b == 1]
letters.sort()
print("letters that occur only once:")

for i in the_letters:
     print(i)
```

This code creates a list of all letters that occur only once by using list comprehension, and then prints them all. items() returns a key-value pair, which can be used to determine if the value of a key is equal to one.

Comment: Question has been clarified by OP; you may want to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, to get the single-occurrence letters in alphabetical order:

```
letter_count = collections.Counter("alphabet")

single_occurrences = sorted([letter for letter, occurrence in letter_count.items() if occurrence == 1])
print(single_occurrences)
# prints: ['b', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'p', 't']
```

Comment: Question has been clarified by OP; you may want to update your answer.