# Select most frequent string in a list, if 'n' strings have the same frequency count then compare alphabetically the first letter of each string

Tags: python, list, sorting, data-structures

I have a list:

```
Fruit_list = ['apples','oranges','peaches','peaches','watermelon','oranges','watermelon']
```

Want to output:

```
print(most_frequent(Fruit_list))
```

which should print out "**oranges**"

I want to find the most frequnent string in the list. The 3 most frequent items are 'oranges','peaches','pears'. However, I want to select **'oranges'** as 'o' is before 'p' and 'w' in the alphabet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076356/2102076

Comment: I receive an error:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: `sorted(Counter(Fruit_list).items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

fruits = ['apples','oranges','peaches','peaches','watermelon','oranges','watermelon']

counter = Counter(fruits)

sorted_fruits = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda tpl: (-tpl[1], tpl[0]))

print(sorted_fruits[0][0])
```

Output:

```
oranges
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a function like this:

```py
def most_frequent(l):
    return max(sorted(l, key=str.lower), key=l.count)

Fruit_list = ['apples','oranges','peaches','peaches','watermelon','oranges','watermelon']
print(most_frequent(Fruit_list))  # outputs "oranges"
```

... if you don't want to use `Counter`.

To clarify:

1. `sorted(l, key=str.lower)` sorts the list `l` lexicographically.
2. `max(<>, key=l.count)` gets the mode of the sorted list.

Comment: Sorry, it does work. I wasn't aware that `max` cares about the order of its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the following:

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['apples','oranges','peaches','peaches','watermelon','oranges','watermelon']
most_common_words= [word for word, word_count in Counter(words).most_common(3)]
most_common_words
```

Comment: This doesn't sort the most common items lexicographically.

Comment: It does, it outputs: ['oranges', 'peaches', 'watermelon'], which is in alphabetical order.

Comment: That's just coincidence, though. In your `words` list change both `oranges` to `zranges`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

Fruit_list = ['apples','zranges','peaches','peaches','watermelon','zranges','watermelon']

max_counter = 0
min_ret = "z"
my_dict = dict(Counter(Fruit_list))


for items in my_dict.keys():
   if my_dict[items] > max_counter:
      max_counter = my_dict[items]
      min_ret = items

   if my_dict[items] == max_counter:
      if items < min_ret:
         min_ret = items

print(min_ret)
```

~

Comment: @user10987432 the Counter sorts the items lexicographically. It also applies to the comment you posted for the previous answer.

Comment: `collections.Counter` doesn't perform any lexicographic sorting.